# To round a value to one decimal place in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$E15 =  $objWorksheet->getCell('E15')->getCalculatedValue();
$asa_impact = round(($E15*100),1);
```

when I use the above code I get answer for ex:-6.6

```
$E16 =  $objWorksheet->getCell('E16')->getCalculatedValue();
$abandon_impact = round(($E16*100),1);
```

But when I use the above code I get the answer for ex:-8.6999999999
I need to fix the issue.

Comment: You can't. Welcome to floating-point numbers.

Comment: can you post your desired result

Comment: @raheelshan: One decimal place. Like the title says.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
$number = 0.0869;
echo $number = $number*100;
echo '<br>';
echo round($number,1);
```

Output

```
8.69    
8.7
```

Comment: would you please tell me a way to get the answer as 8.7

Comment: help me to display the answer as 8 when it is 8.0